# Inserting neighbour coordinates as array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with some points and their coordinates (X, Y, Z), following this structure:

```
>>> inFile
           X             Y           Z  
0     728049.8355  4.395285e+06  201.3366  
1     728049.9077  4.395285e+06  201.3108  
2     728049.9014  4.395285e+06  201.3106  
3     728049.9788  4.395285e+06  201.2823
```

Together with a numpy array that contains the index number of the neighbours of each point:

```
>>> indices_Neighbours
array([array([3], dtype=int64), 
       array([2,3], dtype=int64),
       array([3], dtype=int64),
       array([0], dtype=int64)])
```

My objective is to create a new column in the df that contains for each point an array with the X, Y, Z coordinates of its neighbouring points

```
>>> inFile
           X             Y           Z         Neighbours_Coordinates
0     728049.8355  4.395285e+06  201.3366  [[728049.9788,4.395285e+06,201.2823]]
1     728049.9077  4.395285e+06  201.3108  [[728049.9014,4.395285e+06,201.3106],[728049.9788,4.395285e+06,201.2823]]
2     728049.9014  4.395285e+06  201.3106  [[728049.9788,4.395285e+06,201.2823]]
3     728049.9788  4.395285e+06  201.2823  [[728049.8355,4.395285e+06,201.3366]]
```

Due to the fact that the coordinate file is quite large (several gb), I am trying not to do a for loop. I am thinking in a similar solution to this one instead, but it doesn't work for me:

```
inFile['Neighbours_Coordinates'] =inFile.apply(lambda x: np.array(inFile.X.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors],inFile.Y.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors],inFile.Z.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors]), axis=1)
```

Comment: In my opinion, don't do that since the file is several GBs, You can also get the information when you need it.

Comment: In this case a for loop should be easier and faster than a row-wise apply (which is basically a loop) `inFile['neighbors'] = [inFile.loc[i].to_numpy() for i in indices_Neighbours]`. @Anwarvic is right: looking up the neighbours when needed seems to be more space and time efficient.

Comment: The truth is that this is only an intermediate step to obtain the eigenvalues of the neighbourhood points, which I will use as input variable to classify the points.

Comment: Perhaps [networkx](https://networkx.org) suits your use case better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the best solution I found was to insert the numpy array as a column in the dataframe (indices_Neighbors), and using the function stack of numpy:

```
inFile['Neighbours_Coordinates'] =inFile.apply(lambda x: np.stack([inFile.X.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors],inFile.Y.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors],inFile.Z.iloc[x.indices_Neighbors]], axis=1), axis=1)
```